# select2 change select option icon dynamically

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 for custom select box. But I can't change select option icon. Is it possible to change icon dynamically using jQuery ?

I find icon in Dom ...

```
<span class="select2-item"><i class="ico-status-pending"></i> <span>Pending</span></span>
```

My html ..

```
<div class="aside-head__status-item">
    <div class="select2-wrap">
        <select class="select2-img" data-width="100%">
            <option value="ico-status-pending" selected>Pending</option>
            <option value="ico-status-open">Open</option>
            <option value="ico-status-resolved">Resolved</option>
            <option value="ico-status-close">Closed</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: its not clear could you precise what you want .. what icon do you want to change??

Comment: Frenchy, I want just to have mechanism to change option icon if it possible. My page change dynamically with ajax, I set option attribute active but active icon dose not change no a new one.

Comment: do you want to do a trigger on select2 with the right icon class?

Comment: You should use the select2 API for this - Using `template:Selection` - see https://select2.org/selections#templating

Comment: How are you getting the images into the drop down?   Your code, as provided, does not have any images / icons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if i understand you correctly

If you want to change dynamically the icon, you could trigger the select2 with the desired icon class:

for example:

```
$('.select2-img').val("ico-status-resolved").trigger("change")
```

if you want to use selector directly in the DOM, you could use:

```
   $(".select2-item i").removeClass().addClass("ico-status-open");
   $(".select2-item span").text("Open");
```

of course the solution is different if `$(".select2-item")` is not uniq..

Comment: Frenchy, thaks for anwser. I want to select element <i> and change it class name for example 'ico-status-resolved' to 'ico-status-pending'. How to create selector for it ? And get next span and change text Pending to Open.

Comment: Frenchy, thaks for anwser. I will check.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understand you correctly, do you mean the icon `arrow down` which is displayed in the right corner of the option menu?

If so, then you can change it like this:

```js
$('.select2-img').select2();
```

```css
.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow b {
  background-image: url(https://www.iconninja.com/files/664/91/782/small-arrow-down-icon.png);
  background-color: transparent;
  background-size: contain;
  border: none !important;
  height: 20px !important;
  width: 20px !important;
  margin: auto !important;
  top: auto !important;
  left: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<span class="select2-item"><i class="ico-status-pending"></i> <span>Pending</span></span>


<div class="aside-head__status-item">
  <div class="select2-wrap">
    <select class="select2-img" data-width="80%">
      <option value="ico-status-pending" selected>Pending</option>
      <option value="ico-status-open">Open</option>
      <option value="ico-status-resolved">Resolved</option>
      <option value="ico-status-close">Closed</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than hack away at select2's DOM elements, select2 provides an API exactly for your requirements, the [`templateSelection`](https://select2.org/selections#templating) option.

Your original code doesn't indicate how the icons are displayed/generated, only that the `option` has a `value=` that appears to correspond to your icons (the image also shows them in a different order).

To set how the drop down is displayed after you select an option, use this:

```
$('.select2-img').select2({
  templateSelection: function(data, container) {
    if (data == null || !container) return null;
    return $("<i class='" + data.id + "'></i>");
  }
});
```

where `data.id` = the `option`'s `value=`

if you return a jQuery object, then it will be output as-is, otherwise will be output using `.text()` (and thus remove any html)

Comment: freedomn-m , thaks for anwser. I will check.